# Negativity score for sentences

Tags: computational-linguistics, sentences, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a dataset of airline customer complaints. Since it is "complaints" the general consensus is all the sentence are "negative" sentiment. So I am think of an approach to quantize the negativity score.

For example:

Less Negative review:

```
 "the cabin did not have enough leg space but the food was decent" - Score: 0.3
```

High Negative Review:

```
"complete service was horrible, I will not recommend them ever" - Score: 0.8
```

Any suggestions on existing approaches?

P.S I am not looking for an exact answer, any suggestions on the direction or approaches would be great.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is called **sentiment analysis** aka **opinion mining**; putting either of those into Google will give dozens of different possible starting points.

One model I've used before is [VADER](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment), which is specifically tuned to online reviews and social media posts; if you're using Python, it's available through the NLTK (natural language toolkit) library, or on its own through Pypi.

To get started, you can use something like this:

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
scores = analyzer.polarity_scores(my_sentence)
```

And that's all there is to it! Now `scores` is a dictionary with four keys, giving the probability that the sentence is positive (`pos`), negative (`neg`), or neutral (`neu`), along with an estimate of how intense the feeling is (`compound`: negative values mean negative sentiment, positive values mean the opposite).

There's also a longer demo [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html) if you scroll down to the second heading, showing how you might use it inside a larger program.

Answer (score 0):

There is a large literature on negation.  [Here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/negation/) is a place to start.

Specifically on quantization, it might be interesting to classify various forms of negation with regard to how grammatically oblique they are.  I use numbers corresponding to the 1,2,3 of Relational Grammar, supplemented by a 0 relation for least oblique.  Higher numbers are more oblique, appearing lower down in a grammatical tree structure.  From more to less oblique: "I saw no one ever./I didn't ever see anyone./I never did see anyone./Never did I see anyone."

Comment: I am not focused on negation in particular. I am trying to quantize the complete negative sentiment in the sentence.